# How to set / change the step manually in a metronome counter

Tags: javascript, html

How to manually insert a new value when the counter is stopped, then when I restart the metronome the counter starts from that step?

```js
var inc = 0;//step

    function counter()
    { 
     if(inc < 9){inc = inc+1;}
     else {inc = 0;}
     document.getElementById('btn1').value = inc; //display step
    }

    function metronome()
    {
        //setInterval(function, delay) 
        autoplay = window.setInterval(counter, 
        document.getElementById('btn2').value);
    }
```

```html
    <div><p>metronome speed</p>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="10000" value="500" id="btn2">ms</input>
    <button onclick="metronome()">start</button>
    <button onclick="window.clearInterval(autoplay)">stop</button>
    </div>

 <div><p>counter</p>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="9" value="0" id="btn1">       
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript code to this

```js
var inc = 0;
function counter() {
  if (inc < 9) {
    inc = inc + 1;
  } else {
    inc = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("btn1").value = inc; //display step
}

function metronome() {
  autoplay = window.setInterval(counter, document.getElementById("btn2").value);
}

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("input", e => {
  inc = parseInt(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<div><p>metronome speed</p>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="10000" value="500" id="btn2">ms</input>
  <button onclick="metronome()">start</button>
  <button onclick="window.clearInterval(autoplay)">stop</button>
  </div>

<div><p>counter</p>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="9" value="0" id="btn1">       
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

What this will do is when you change the value of the second input `btn1` ( which display the value of `inc`), it will set its value to `inc`.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. I'm not able to get your code working inside my JS. Is there something not mentioned I need to do?

Comment: I changed the code so that you will know where to add the code

Comment: Sorry your code does not work, you can't manually change btn1 aka "counter" without having the metronome straight continue its own count. Did you try it?

Comment: I think the window.setInterval is a little difficult to tame :)

Comment: @lairom yes my friend, I it ran, that is why I included the whole code. It may be possible that I am not getting what exactly do you want

Comment: are you entering nos. greater than 9. because if you are then the inc will reset

Comment: if you change the value of btn1 manually, the inc will be set to its value and then it will begin its count from there

Comment: That's okay. You only miss to explain that it should be in the counter function itself ;-)